# Compare multiple textbox - Make sure 1 is entered

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

In my Content page I have 4 different `TextBox`'s which is used to enter phone number - Mobile, Office Phone, Office Mobile & Other. I have `RegularExpressionValidator` for each.

I want to make sure atleast one of the above 4 textbox's has entered a value. I didn't find any example or article on net showing this situation.  One way I think is in `Submit` button click, before `Page.IsValid` call, call a function that checks that one of the control has valid value. If the function returns false, show `MessageBox`.  Is their any other way using `Validators` or so to comfirm that one textbox out of 4 has a valid value.

What can be the best way to achieve this ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thankss

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Custom Validator in ASP.NET.

This post should help you out.

[asp.net required field validator for at least one textbox contains text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915994/asp-net-required-field-validator-for-at-least-one-textbox-contains-text)