# Exclusive RequiredFieldValidation among multiple Textboxes

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm developing a web form which consists of a set of TextBoxes, as per the system requirements, the users are requested to fill-up AT LEAST ONE of those TextBoxes. If RequiredFieldValidation is used, how can I achieve such requirement? Please kindly advise.

Thank you very much!
William

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CustomValidator, you can refer to this question:

[asp.net validate textbox - at least one text box must have data in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443545/asp-net-validate-textbox-at-least-one-text-box-must-have-data-in)